# How to replace broken images with a blank image in JSF?

Tags: java, jsp, jsf

I'm using the `h:graphicImage` tag in JSF. Is there a way to show a blank image (i.e. blank.jpg) if there is a broken or not found image?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

- client side - with javascript, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images)
- server side (less preferable) make an `ImageServlet` which takes an image url, loads it and sees if it exists. If it exists, it is streamed to to client. If not - the blank.jpg is streamed to the client. Verification can be done via `new File(fullPathToImage).exists()`, or, if the image is not on your server, using `URL.openConnection()`.